# Why is JButton.enable deprecated?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, deprecated

Why is Button.enable deprecated? I need to use the method of my button but it's deprecated, so it has no effect.

How can I fix it? Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: why don't you read the api doc? You need to understand the doc so your coding is successful. You can fix the issue by reading. There are no alternatives to reading.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [JDK documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#enable%28%29):

> Deprecated. As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by
>   java.awt.Component.setEnabled(boolean)

So call the `setEnabled(true)` method instead.